# How to move this menu to the right?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm having troubles moving contents of this menu to the right. I want to keep logo on the same position, but move other objects to the right. Please help me. Here is the code

```js
// Dropdown Menu Fade    
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dropdown").hover(
        function() { $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop().fadeIn("fast");
        },
        function() { $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop().fadeOut("fast");
    });
});
```

```css
.navbar-default{
color: #fff;
background-color: #ccc6c6;
border-color: #aca1a2;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a{
 color:#fff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a .caret{
 border-top-color: #fff;
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand{
 color:#fff;
}
.menu-large {
  position: static !important;
}
.megamenu{
  padding: 20px 0px;
  width:100%;
}
.megamenu> li > ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.megamenu> li > ul > li {
  list-style: none;
}
.megamenu> li > ul > li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #333333;
  white-space: normal;
}
.megamenu> li ul > li > a:hover,
.megamenu> li ul > li > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #262626;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.megamenu.disabled > a,
.megamenu.disabled > a:hover,
.megamenu.disabled > a:focus {
  color: #999999;
}
.megamenu.disabled > a:hover,
.megamenu.disabled > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
.megamenu.dropdown-header {
  color: #428bca;
  font-size: 18px;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .megamenu{
    margin-left: 0 ;
    margin-right: 0 ;
  }
  .megamenu> li {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .megamenu> li:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .megamenu.dropdown-header {
    padding: 3px 15px !important;

  }
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header{
 color:#fff;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown menu-large">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Product Listing <b class="caret"></b> </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu megamenu row">
            <li>
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x120" />
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x120" />
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x120" />
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x120" />
                </a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="dropdown menu-large">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Categories <b class="caret"></b></a> 
          <ul class="dropdown-menu megamenu row">
            <li class="col-sm-3">
              <ul>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Glyphicons</li>
                <li><a href="#">Available glyphs</a>
                </li>
                <li class="disabled"><a href="#">How to use</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Examples</a>
                </li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Dropdowns</li>
                <li><a href="#">Example</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Aligninment options</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Headers</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Disabled menu items</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="col-sm-3">
              <ul>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Button groups</li>
                <li><a href="#">Basic example</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Button toolbar</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Sizing</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Nesting</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Vertical variation</a>
                </li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Button dropdowns</li>
                <li><a href="#">Single button dropdowns</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="col-sm-3">
              <ul>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Input groups</li>
                <li><a href="#">Basic example</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Sizing</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Checkboxes and radio addons</a>
                </li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Navs</li>
                <li><a href="#">Tabs</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Pills</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Justified</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="col-sm-3">
              <ul>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Navbar</li>
                <li><a href="#">Default navbar</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Buttons</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Text</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Non-nav links</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Component alignment</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Fixed to top</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Fixed to bottom</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Static top</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Inverted navbar</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/8npLzegk/)

Comment: code is not there

Comment: it is better for everyone if you copy and paste your code directly onto this page

Comment: There is a class in bootstrap named by `navbar-right` you can use it.

Comment: `.navbar-collapse {  float: right;}` should work.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a tour of the help centre to see how to ask a good question.  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Comment: works fine now,..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set 
 `position:relative` 
and play around with the margin

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your CSS:

```
ul.navbar-nav{
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: Why would use this when bootstrap have class `navbar-right`

Comment: I never use Bootstrap, so this was a quick answer to solve his problem, which works. He can also use navbar-right yes ;)